# How I rotate an image with swipe gesture from an anchor point in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here,I rotate an image given angle. But I want to rotate an image with swipe gesture from an anchor point.Here is my code..

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //circleName is an UIImageView IBoutlet

        _circleNames=@"Squre.png";
        _showCircle=[UIImage imageNamed:_circleNames];
        _circleView.image=_showCircle;


       // Here I am setting anchor point 
         _circleView.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

        //here I am setting animation

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:6];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

      //rotate 170 degree angle
        _circleView.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(_circleView.transform,170);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: 170 degree? 170 in radians more likely.

Comment: may be. :) I am new in iOS.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to dynamically rotate image following your finger you must use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (not `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`). It gives you point of your finger in repeatedly called selector you provide.

**UPDATE**:

You can use this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* rotView;

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* _panGesture;
    float _deltaAngle;
    CGAffineTransform _startTransform;
    CGPoint _prevPoint;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateItem:)];
    _panGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.rotView addGestureRecognizer:_panGesture];
}

- (void) rotateItem:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint currPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint center = recognizer.view.center;

    CGFloat ang = atan2f(currPoint.y - center.y, currPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(_prevPoint.y - center.y, _prevPoint.x - center.x);

    _prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    _deltaAngle += ang;

    self.rotView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_startTransform, _deltaAngle);
}

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    _startTransform = self.rotView.transform;

    return YES;
}

@end
```

**UPDATE2**

I've created class (and category) with sample on github:
https://github.com/faviomob/UIRotatableView

Comment: Thanks. But I want to move/rotate image from an anchor point when I touch my finger . I will be grateful if you help me by giving code.

Comment: I rotate an item/imageview successfully from your update code.But my task is showing four images or moving these images one by one when rotate the item.

Comment: @Md.AshikMahmud just place one image inside one view and set the custom class of this view as UIRatatableView in Interface builder (and ensure that rotatable property is set to YES). No other code if you use my library on github (see update2).

Comment: thanks..but my task is change somehow.Here is my new question,please comment here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736270/how-more-images-show-one-by-one-according-to-the-rotation-of-an-item

I also try your class,but there is an error in IB_DESIGNABLE . My Xcode doesn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to rotate your image 90degrees.

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```